# How to manage credentials in Julia?

Tags: database, api, julia, credentials

I recently started using the [Julia programming langauge](https://julialang.org) and have had difficulty locating any package (or even, just, an explanation of best practice) to manage sensitive credentials, say, when connecting to a database or using various APIs.

One approach I've been using is to encode credentials into a .csv or .json file, then load the file in:

```
using CSV

credentials = CSV.read("C:/Users/jkix/credentials.csv")
username = credentials[:usr][1]
password = credentials[:pw][1]
```

The problem with this approach are obvious:
1. Julia prints the values of assignments to the screen by default, so even though the above code is portable and doesn't require any hard-coding of credentials, those credentials are visible to anyone who happens to look over your shoulder.
2. .csv and .json files store data in plaintext anyway

**tl;dr**: Is there a Julia package in existence for credential management?

Comment: Point 1 only applies in the REPL, if you don't end your statement with. Semicolon. But anyway good question.

Comment: @LyndonWhite thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any package that does all the stuff. What I did, when I had to deal with it last time is encrypting the credentials (both in file and memory) using [Nettle.jl](https://github.com/staticfloat/Nettle.jl) and only decrypt right before accessing the service.
An alternative would be [MbedTLS.jl](https://pkg.julialang.org//docs/MbedTLS/bf9T0/0.7.0/) or calling to your favorite library via `run`.